# c++ memory leaks when using buffer to write to file

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a system with many threads that are being activated on Linux system. Each thread allocates a buffer in a certain size and when this buffer is full writes it to a file. Each thread has his own buffer and writes the buffer to a different file. I've discovered that when I set the buffer size to be relatively large (1M size or bigger) I start to suffer from memory leaks. However when the buffer is small - about 1K or less - I don't have these memory leaks.

Anyone knows what's the reason for it? And more important how can I overcome this problem? Using smaller buffers can highly affect my system's performance.

writting to the buffer - 
else if(m_bUseBuffer)
        {
            //Data buffer is now full
            if (m_nBufferSize+pi_nDataLength >= cMaxSizeQLoaderFileBuffer)
            {
                hRes = WriteDataToFile();
            }

```
        if (SUCCEEDED(hRes)) 
        {
            if (m_nBufferSize+pi_nDataLength <= cMaxSizeQLoaderFileBuffer) 
            {
                memcpy(m_sBuffer+m_nBufferSize,pi_pData,pi_nDataLength);

                m_nBufferSize += pi_nDataLength;

                m_nBufferLinesCounter++;

                //need to write buffer to file otherwise next time we write the file will be too large.
                if (m_nBufferLinesCounter + m_nQLoaderFileLinesCounter >= m_nQLoaderFileMaxLines) 
                {
                    hRes = WriteDataToFile();
                }
            }
```

writting the buffer to file-

```
            hRes = OpenFile();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
    {
        m_fQLoaderFile.write(m_sBuffer,m_nBufferSize);
        m_fQLoaderFile.flush();

        m_nBufferSize = 0;
        m_nQLoaderFileLinesCounter += m_nBufferLinesCounter;
        m_nBufferLinesCounter = 0;
    }
```

when is from type- std::ofstream

Comment: impossible to see without looking at some sample code that reproduces.

Comment: can you give us some code to work with? Vague questions yield vague responses

Comment: How do you know you are seeing memory leaks? Perhaps the problem is actually memory fragmentation?

Comment: I see the leaks using a simple top. 
I'll try to give the relevant code below.

Comment: top does not indicate a memory leak. When you free memory it is returned to your *program*, it does not have to be returned to the *system*. That only happens when you exit your program. Since top indicates the memory available to the system it can indicate that your program is using more and more memory but by itself this does not mean a memory leak. If you want freed memory to be returned to the system, you are going to have to do more sophisticated and platform specific memory management.

Comment: John - I see that the memory that is in use by the program keeps raising. You say it doesn't necessarly indicate system's leak?

Comment: Yes, it could indicate memory fragmentation as I said. You are freeing memory correctly, but as your program runs the heap gets fragmented so that there isn't enough *contiguous* memory to satisfy your allocation requests. So your program keeps asking the system to give it more memory. If this is right you could (for instance) preallocate all the buffer memory that your threads will need, and then hand it out as the threads require it. That way you program only makes one very big allocation at the start of the program instead of multiple big allocations as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Because your question is too vague, I can only give you a generic answer: check your code with `valgrind`, it will report all memory leaks.

BTW if your code was correct, the buffer size wouldn't matter.

Comment: Valgrind- I tried didn't gave my any response. 
I guess something is wrong with the code, but this behavior is weird.

Comment: I assume you saw the valgrind header (that it started, etc..). if no reports, no memleak... (note: as long as there is a pointer for the allocated space, it is not considered as a leak)

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to wrap the threads (or their buffers) up in a [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) wrapper? That is, stack allocated wrapper object with overloaded private new operator (to prevent accidental heap allocation) with heap allocation of the buffer occurring in the constructor and de-allocation occurring in the destructor?

Alternatively: Is a fixed length (stack allocated) buffer perhaps appropriate for your problem?

Comment: I'll try using fixed length and tell you how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly impossible to answer this question without more details. As @karoly suggested, if your code was correct - buffer size wouldn't matter.

The one thing I can think of when buffer size matter is that maybe some allocation fails when buffer size is too big. Then, when this happens, potentially you have code that doesn't clean very well in such conditions (either you don't catch an exception, or don't test for error condition).

Comment: But i allocate the buffer once and reuse it all over the code without re-allocate it.